# Multiple Checkbox Name - Getting the value of checkebox after it was clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I want to get the value of the checkbox after it was clicked using javascript or jquery. Some checkbox was checked, some are not

```
<input type="checkbox" name="place[]" value="USA" checked>
<input type="checkbox" name="place[]" value="Canada">
<input type="checkbox" name="place[]" value="Japan" checked>
<input type="checkbox" name="place[]" value="Russia">
```

I want to get the value after the checkbox was clicked, whether it was checked or not.

```
Sample, If I've clicked : `<input type="checkbox" name="place[]" value="Russia">`
Result: Russia

Sample, If I've clicked : `<input type="checkbox" name="place[]" value="Japan">`
Result: Japan
```

How can I achieve this using javascript or jquery.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks :)

**UPDATED**

I'm using bootstrap toggle buttons.
Using below codes: It doesn't work.

```
  <link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.0/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.0/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $('#toggle-two').bootstrapToggle({
      on: 'Enabled',
      off: 'Disabled'
    });
    $('[name="place[]"]').change(function() {
      console.log(this.value)
    })
  </script>
  <input type="checkbox" name="place[]" value="USA" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-size="mini" data-onstyle="primary" data-offstyle="danger" data-on="Enabled" data-off="Disabled">
  <input type="checkbox" name="place[]" value="Canada" data-toggle="toggle" data-size="mini" data-onstyle="primary" data-offstyle="danger" data-on="Enabled" data-off="Disabled">
  <input type="checkbox" name="place[]" value="Japan" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-size="mini" data-onstyle="primary" data-offstyle="danger" data-on="Enabled" data-off="Disabled">
  <input type="checkbox" name="place[]" value="Russia" data-toggle="toggle" data-size="mini" data-onstyle="primary" data-offstyle="danger" data-on="Enabled" data-off="Disabled">
```

Comment: Give same class name to all checkboxes. and get value on click of checkbox

Answer (score 2):

Bind a click event handler to listen to the click event.

```
$('[name="place[]"]').click(function() {
  console.log(this.value)
})
```

```js
$('[name="place[]"]').click(function() {
  console.log(this.value)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="place[]" value="USA" checked>
<input type="checkbox" name="place[]" value="Canada">
<input type="checkbox" name="place[]" value="Japan" checked>
<input type="checkbox" name="place[]" value="Russia">
```

**UPDATE 1:** But it always better to use change event handler to listen to checkbox or radio buttons.

```
$('[name="place[]"]').change(function() {
  console.log(this.value)
})
```

```js
$('[name="place[]"]').change(function() {
  console.log(this.value)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="place[]" value="USA" checked>
<input type="checkbox" name="place[]" value="Canada">
<input type="checkbox" name="place[]" value="Japan" checked>
<input type="checkbox" name="place[]" value="Russia">
```

---

**UPDATE 2:** In pure JavaScript :

```
// for older browser use [].slice.call to convert into array
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[name="place[]"]')).forEach(function(ele) {
  // bind cahange event handler
  ele.addEventListener('change', function() {
    console.log(this.value)
  })
});
```

```js
// for older browser use [].slice.call
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[name="place[]"]')).forEach(function(ele) {
  ele.addEventListener('change', function() {
    console.log(this.value)
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="place[]" value="USA" checked>
<input type="checkbox" name="place[]" value="Canada">
<input type="checkbox" name="place[]" value="Japan" checked>
<input type="checkbox" name="place[]" value="Russia">
```

---

**UPDATE 3:** The same code with `bootstrapToggle` plugin. Your code is failing because you are trying to attach handler before the element is loading, to resolve that use [document ready handler](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) or move the script tag after the input elements.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#toggle-two').bootstrapToggle({
    on: 'Enabled',
    off: 'Disabled'
  });
  $('[name="place[]"]').change(function() {
    console.log(this.value)
  })
});
```

```html
<link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.0/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.0/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="place[]" value="USA" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-size="mini" data-onstyle="primary" data-offstyle="danger" data-on="Enabled" data-off="Disabled">
<input type="checkbox" name="place[]" value="Canada" data-toggle="toggle" data-size="mini" data-onstyle="primary" data-offstyle="danger" data-on="Enabled" data-off="Disabled">
<input type="checkbox" name="place[]" value="Japan" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-size="mini" data-onstyle="primary" data-offstyle="danger" data-on="Enabled" data-off="Disabled">
<input type="checkbox" name="place[]" value="Russia" data-toggle="toggle" data-size="mini" data-onstyle="primary" data-offstyle="danger" data-on="Enabled" data-off="Disabled">
```

Comment: Thanks  @Pranav :)